# In C#, how do I initialize an Object with key/value from an Collection

Tags: c#

I am too lazy to type out all the properties of my object, so instead of this:

```
myObj.property1 = value1;
myObj.property2 = value2;
myObj.property3 = value3;
myObj.property4 = value4;
myObj.property5 = value5;
...
```

Is there way to just do this?

```
Object myObj = new Object();
foreach (string curProperty in myCollection.AllKeys) {
    var curValue = collection[curProperty];
    myObj[curProperty] = curValue;   // ??????????????

}
```

Comment: You can use reflection to do this, but the code will perform slower than doing it manually.

Comment: @David, I have not found reflection to perform significantly slower in situations like this. There are times of course that performing significant lookups against types will take more time than directly accessing some section of memory - but I'm pretty sure that whatever the performance hit is here it's negligible.

Comment: You *can* do this with reflection, but you *should not* do so unless you have a very good reason. (Hint: Laziness is not a good reason.)

Comment: Was that edit really necessary?

Comment: Fine, Fine, some guy was telling me to stop being a programmer, so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to use `System.Reflection` to get the job done:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
{
    PropertyInfo prop = myObj.GetType().GetProperty(string.Format("property{0}", i);
    if (prop == null) { continue; }
    prop.SetValue(myObj, collection[prop.Name], null);
}
```

In this example I'm assuming that `collection` has a string indexer on property name (you may need to recover it a different way). I'm also assuming there are only 5 properties (`i < 6`), you'll need to set that accordingly. But you get the idea.

---

In the spirit of the comment made by Jim Mischel, serialization is an option as well. I'm not going to work out an example here because I'm not 100% on the code, but consider web services. Web services do all their work with (de)serialization.

So, you could technically deserialize an XML file into an object and you would get all of the benefits of deserialization - and there are quite a few. One that I can think of off the top of my head is that a new instance of the object ***is not created*** before setting the values of the properties - how the framework does that I'm not sure - but I know it's done because I chased a *bug* like that one time!

Comment: Just thinking about somebody doing this makes me nervous. I realize that you're just showing *how*, not necessarily advocating actually *doing* it ... still . . . **shudder**

Comment: @JimMischel, I've built some extremely dynamic applications in which it was necessary to perform these types of operations because I never knew what was going to be configured. In **very simple** situations like this I haven't found a significant decrease in performance - but when you're entire application is *interpreted* - yeah that's **a lot slower**. I've seen both sides of the coin - and programmed both sides of the coin. LOL

Comment: Oh, I've done it, too. I prefer, though, when the tooling handles this kind of stuff (serialization, for example). If the tool handles both sides, I'm okay. When one side has to be hand-written, it's like a loaded gun aimed at your foot . . .

Comment: @JimMischel, now that's one way of looking at it! Serialization is an interesting approach, and now that you mention it, I would have used it had I thought of that. Export the configuration as little XML files that can simply be deserialized and I get all the benefits of the performance enhancements that exist in that space. Fantastic thought!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with reflection, but keep in mind that this will be quite a bit slower than doing it properly.

It should be something like this:

```
var prop = typeof(SomeType).GetProperty(propertyName);
prop.SetValue(myObj, newValue, null);
```

This assumes that the property exists and is accessible.

You can improve the performance of this significantly using [expression trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) and saving the newly-created lambdas in memory, but that is a bit complex to write.

Overall, I'd say "don't do this" unless you're just using it as an exercise to learn how to use reflection.

Answer (score 1):

Use System.Reflection and the code would look like this:

```
Object myObj = new Object();
foreach (string curProperty in myCollection.AllKeys) {
    var property= typeof(Object).GetProperty(curProperty);
    property.SetValue(myObj, curValue, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not exactly what you are asking for and reflection solves the specific question you are asking; but the Expando object is great if you are lazy and you already have a key/value collection.  This way you don't even need to declare a class at all!!!

[ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx)